# Generate Dynamic data in cucumber table

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Hi I want to generate dynamic data in the cucumber tables:

```
Feature: Generate dynamic data

 Scenario Outline:
 
  When open url

  Then get the price list and save to "Price List" in context 

  #Note: Price list is an array and returned as [10, 20, 30, 40] and this is dynamic

  When send "<singlepricelist" to server

  .......the remaining steps....

 Examples:

 | singlepricelist |

 | <<Price List   |
```

Question: In the step "When send "", I want to send the values present in arraylist one by one i.e. the said step in this example should run 4 times with the values 10, 20, 30 and 40.

Can I generate the dynamic data in the Examples so that the above step will run 4 times? Note: singlepricelist can take only one value at a time.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot use the feature file to do any programming. So you cannot pass dynamic values from the feature file.

If you want to perform the above scenario with the listed values (10, 20, 30 and 40), you can add each of them as an example.

If you want the values to be dynamic / random, you can implement this in your step definition. In that case, rather than sending the values from your feature file, you would generate them in the implementation of your step definition. In that case I don't understand why you would want to run it 4 times.

To be honest, I don't understand your use case from the question. Can you explain the reason you want to send 4 dynamic values? (what is the problem you are trying to solve with this?)

Comment: I know that we should not do any programming language in feature file and hence I asked the same if is there any way or any alternative available to archive this. The Scenario is: I am a mobile subscriber and I provisioned 4 services (say service ids, 10, 20, 30, 40) for voice, sms, data and xyz. Now I want to unprovision all the services but the limitation is only 1 service will be unprovisioned at a time. So my steps would be 1) 1st extract the list of services the subscriber has and after getting the list 2) send unprovision request with one service id based on the list size.

Comment: Additionally as you suggested I will implement it in the step definition instead of feature file.